# How to suppress Warning by sbt compile

Tags: scala, logging, sbt, suppress-warnings

I am currently working on project, my project works fine and working. But i want to suppress the warning when i run `sbt compile`. when i run `sbt compile` i don't want my terminal to show warning.

```
[warn] /Users/kumarshubham/Documents/repositories/alice/app/misc/QueryDB.scala:14: imported `QueryString' is permanently hidden by   definition of class QueryString in package misc
[warn] import misc.QueryString
[warn]             ^
[warn] /Users/kumarshubham/Documents/repositories/alice/app/misc/QueryDB.scala:26: method apply in trait WithResult is deprecated: Use   [[fold]], [[foldWhile]] or [[withResult]] instead, which manages resources and memory
[warn]       val resultSet = query().map(
[warn]                       ^
[warn] /Users/kumarshubham/Documents/repositories/alice/app/misc/QueryDB.scala:58: method apply in trait WithResult is deprecated: Use [[fold]], [[foldWhile]] or [[withResult]] instead, which manages resources and memory
[warn]       val resultSet = query().map(
[warn]                       ^
[warn] /Users/kumarshubham/Documents/repositories/alice/app/misc/QueryDB.scala:89: method apply in trait WithResult is deprecated: Use [[fold]], [[foldWhile]] or [[withResult]] instead, which manages resources and memory
[warn]       val resultSet = query().map(
[warn]                       ^
[warn] /Users/kumarshubham/Documents/repositories/alice/app/misc/QueryDB.scala:121: method apply in trait WithResult is deprecated: Use [[fold]], [[foldWhile]] or [[withResult]] instead, which manages resources and memory
[warn]         val resultSet = query().map(
[warn]                         ^
[warn] /Users/kumarshubham/Documents/repositories/alice/app/misc/QueryDB.scala:329: method apply in trait WithResult is deprecated: Use [[fold]], [[foldWhile]] or [[withResult]] instead, which manages resources and memory
[warn]       val resultSet = query().map(
[warn]                       ^
[warn] /Users/kumarshubham/Documents/repositories/alice/app/misc/QueryDB.scala:351: method apply in trait WithResult is deprecated: Use [[fold]], [[foldWhile]] or [[withResult]] instead, which manages resources and memory
[warn]       val resultSet = query().map(
[warn]                       ^
[warn] 7 warnings found
```

Comment: you want to turn off warning completely for whole project?

Comment: @Mysterion yep right

Comment: Without knowing the specifics, my general approach would be to eliminate the *cause* of the warning, rather than suppress it

Comment: In my case, I generate a lot of java code that compiles without warnings under `javac`, but `scalac` produces warnings about things like `Collection<Class>`.  Fixing the generator is hard, so I just want to ignore them.

Answer (score 13):

**SBT** documentation have a perfect manual on how to update logging level for whole project or just for one task.

You need to do something like this:

```
set logLevel in compile := Level.Error
```

If you want to set this level in your **sbt** file, you could do that, by adding this line into your **build.sbt** file

```
logLevel := Level.Error
```

Also if you want to specify *logLevel* only for *compile* task it will be a little bit tricky, since you're probably need to set level for dependent tasks as well.

For more information take a look here - http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Howto-Logging.html

Comment: i want something that i can put in build.sbt

Comment: That is a global log level. How to inform SBT that we're aware of this warning in this specific line of code and we're good with that? is there a way?