# How to fix WARNING: -c has been deprecated

Tags: scala, maven, scalatest, scala-maven-plugin

I'm doing `mvn clean install` and getting this error:

```
[INFO] --- scalatest-maven-plugin:1.1.3:test (test) @ tests ---
WARNING: -c has been deprecated and will be reused for a different (but still very cool) purpose in ScalaTest 2.0. Please change all uses of -c to -P.
An exception or error caused a run to abort. This may have been caused by a problematic custom reporter.
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class org.objectweb.asm.tree.ClassNode has interface org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor as super class
```

Comment: @SuppressWarning(“depercation”) annotation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to suppress Warning by sbt compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31934645/how-to-suppress-warning-by-sbt-compile)

Comment: @RamanMishra that one is a bit different will look too, thanks